# Retaining numeric lists (stop converting to string) when converting a data frame to a dictionary using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I would like to convert a pandas dataframe into a dictionary. This dataset has a number of variables which as stored as lists, i.e. [0,2,5,6]. When I convert the data frame to a dictionary using pd.to_dict these lists are stored as strings rather than numerical lists (i.e. '[0,2,5,6]' instead of [0,2,5,6]). Is there an easy way to perform this operation, or do I need to iterate over the list of dictionaries after conversion? If that is required, how would that iteration be performed?

```
NDF = DF.to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

Current output:

```
..., 'Description': 'Version 5.1', 'Coord': '[128, 32]', 'Elev': '[0.19, 0.43]', 'Strength': 150,...
```

Desired Output:

```
..., 'Description': 'Version 5.1', 'Coord': [128, 32], 'Elev': [0.19, 0.43], 'Strength': 150.0, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:

```
a = ''
a = a.split()
a[0] = a[0][1:]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = a[i][:-1]
    a[i] = int(a[i])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over your current output like this (assuming there's no nested list as the value of any key)

```
current_output = {
    'Description': 'Version 5.2',
    'Coord': '[128, 32]',
    'Elev': '[0.19, 0.43]',
    'Strength': 150
    }

for k, v in current_output.items():
    if type(current_output[k]) == str and current_output[k].startswith('['):
        current_output[k] = [float(i) for i in current_output[k][1:-1].split(',')]

print(current_output)
>> {'Description': 'Version 5.2', 'Coord': [128.0, 32.0], 'Elev': [0.19, 0.43], 'Strength': 150}
```